# My program is not giving me the right answer... C

Tags: c

I hope you can help me out. I have everything written out and compiling but im not getting the answer that i want.

User enters a code of 1's and 0's and my program then finds the correct sequence for example...

if user enters 1000110
the error bit should be 6
and the corrected code should be 1100110.

I originally used char's but it kept printing out random things at the end instead of 1's and 0's.

can anyone help me out?

I will further explain anything if need be...

### *edit i added my original code. I was giving int a try but it didnt work out. It seems that with this code below, the 1's and 0's entered by the user arent being placed into the array or they just wont print right... I dont know what to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

   char *code = NULL;
   int length, parity,slength;
   void param(){
      printf("Enter the maximum length:");
      scanf("%d",&length);
      printf("Enter the parity (0=even, 1=odd):");
      scanf("%d",&parity);
      code = (char*)malloc(length *sizeof(char));
      return;
   }
   void check(){
      int error,p,q=0,j,k,l,u=0,b=0,h,total;
      char *hCode = NULL;
      char *fCode = NULL;
      hCode = (char*)malloc(length *sizeof(char));
        fCode = (char*)malloc(length *sizeof(char));
      printf("Enter the Hamming code:");
      scanf("%lengths",&code);
        slength = strlen(code);
//      printf("%d",&slength);
//      int z;
//      for(z=0;z<slength;z++){
//          printf("%s\n",&code[z]);
//      }
      for (p=slength+1;p>=0;p--){
         hCode[p] = code[q];
         q++;
      }
      for (j=1;j<=log2(length);j*=2){
         int bit;
         for (k=j;k<=length;k+=j*2)
            for (l=0;l<j||k+l<=length;l++){
               if(k+1!=k){
                  bit^=hCode[k+l];
                  fCode[k+1] = hCode[k+1];
               }
                 fCode[j] = bit;
            }
      }
      for (u=1;u<=slength+1;u++){
         if (hCode[u]!=fCode[u]){
            error = u;
                b=u;
            printf("There is an error in bit: %d\n",error);
         }
        }
            if (b==0)
                printf("There is no bit error\n");
            b=0;
      printf("The corrected Hamming code is: ");
      for (h=slength;h>0;h--){
         printf("%c",&fCode[h]);
      }
        printf("\n");
       return;
   }

   int main(){
      int choice;
      while (choice !=3){
         printf("\n");
         printf(" Error detection/correction:\n");
         printf("------------------------------\n");
         printf("1) Enter parameters\n");
         printf("2) Check Hamming code\n");
         printf("3) Exit\n");
         printf("\nEnter selection: ");
         scanf("%d",&choice);
         printf("\n");
         if (choice == 1)
            param();
         else if (choice == 2)
            check();            
         else{ 
            printf("\n");
            printf("Goodbye. Have a nice day");
         }
      }
      return 1;
   }
```

Comment: What is the error / incorrect output you're seeing

Answer (score 2):

`scanf("%lengthd",code);` won't read an array into `code`; it's not even valid `scanf` syntax. You should read the characters in a loop:

```
for (p=0;p<length;p++){
    code[p] = getc() - '0';
}
```

P.S. There are some other issues. For example, `sizeof(code)/sizeof(int)` does *not* get the size of the array, but instead only gets `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`. You probably just want `length` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed my original post... if you are still willing to help please look at it again... I posted my original code

Answer (score 0):

The first thing wrong is this:

```
 for (p=(sizeof(code)/sizeof(int))+1;p>=0;p--)
```

code is of type INT *, which is typically 4 bytes long, depending on your system of course. But anyway what that expression will evaluate to is 4/4 = 1, which I suspect isn't what you're after. I suspect you should be using your length variable.

ie

```
for (p=0; p < length; p++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed my original post... if you are still willing to help please look at it again... I posted my original code

Comment: What is going wrong? From a quick look the first thing I noticed is that your hCode array isn't allocated enough space - you're forgetting the null terminator. Try `hCode = (char*)malloc(1 + length *sizeof(char));`. Also for fCode too, and I don't see why you're copying the string into hCode at all. Also don't forget to free memory allocated with malloc, using free.